# Proving a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to prove that the deduction takes place: $$\frac{B\:\lor\:C,\:B\to \:A,\:C\to \:A}{A}$$
and I know how to do this using truth tables, but it specifically asks I use normal forms(Conjunctive normal form or disjunctive normal form).

I know that the deduction I have is the same as writing $$\left(B \lor C\right) \land \left(B\to \:A\right) \land\left(C\to \:A\right)\:\to \:A$$
and proving it's a tautology
and that $A\to \:B$ is basicaly $\lnot A \lor B$
but I don't know how to take it from there.

When I write $\lor$ I mean "OR". Does my question make any sense to you? I've never had to ask a logic question here before.

Comment: Just a note that you can achieve the correct **l**ogical **or** symbol $\lor$ using the `\lor` command. Similarly with `\land` for $\land$.

Comment: You are on the right track... Consider the *antecedent* : $(B∨C)∧(B→A)∧(C→A)$; upon rewriting with the equivalence between $P \to Q$ and $\lnot P \lor Q$, you have to use *distributivity* in order to simplify it.

Comment: I've tried simplifying this but the fact that I have 3 terms makes it harder(and I'm probably getting something wrong), and I'm supposed to get a conjunction of disjunctions where I have the atomic propositions and their negations, but I'm not getting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider :

> $(B∨C)∧(B→A)∧(C→A)$

and rewrite it as :

> $(B \lor C)∧(\lnot B \lor A)∧(\lnot C \lor A)$

that is :

> $(B \lor C)∧[(\lnot B ∧ \lnot C) \lor A]$

by [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property).

By *Distributivity* again, we get :

> $[(B \lor C)∧(\lnot B ∧ \lnot C)] \lor [(B \lor C) \land A]$

that is equivalent to $(B \lor C) \land A$, because the left disjunct is $FALSE$.

Thus, the original formula is equivalent to :

> > $[(B \lor C) \land A] \to A$

and this is simply [Conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination).